# How to run some task at specified time interval in android using AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Hello `stackoverflow` I'm trying to develop an android application that can run some task at specific time interval, I'm using `AlarmManager` to do the task, the code snippet is as follows,

```
if (radioBtnChecked)
{   
     MyActivity.this.alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) MyActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class);
     MyActivity.this.pi = PendingIntent.getService(MyActivity.this, 0, serviceIntent, 0);
     MyActivity.this.alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 10000, pi);

 }//End of if condition
```

and `MyService.java`

```
public class MyService extends Service 
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }//End of onBind method

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Problem is the `Service started` message will be displayed for the very first time when I click the radio button, but I want the `Service started` message to be displayed after the `10 seconds`. Please someone help me to solve this problem, please share your knowledge so that I can correct my mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set AlarmManager like this:

```
private static final int REPEAT_TIME_IN_SECONDS = 60; //repeat every 60 seconds

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            REPEAT_TIME_IN_SECONDS * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Change `AlarmManager.RTC` to `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` if u want to wake up phone when it
 goes off. More about AlarmManager [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Those two parameters also means that your alarm time will be [`System.currentTimeMilis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) which is time in UTC.

**EDIT :**

Your solution using `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` which measure time since device boot including sleep. It means that if you want run this code after 10 seconds and then want to repeat it and your device is running for more than that, **PendingIntent will be triggered immediately because 10 seconds after boot occurs in the past.**

**EDIT 2 :**

If u want to run code just once after 10 seconds try this:

```
private static final int START_AFTER_SECONDS = 10;
...
if (radioBtnChecked)
{ 
    Runnable mRunnable;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyService.class);
            MyActivity.this.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, START_AFTER_SECONDS * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Swierczek or your detailed explanation, but its not working, issue remains.

Comment: I want to keep on running the code after 10 seconds for every 10 seconds @Sebastian Swierczek

Comment: @ChethanShetty so then try to mix it, inside `run()` of my second code put my first code. It will set after 10 seconds AlarmManager to work repeatedly.

Comment: Wow thanks @Sebastian Swierczek, its really working, but how to stop/kill thread ?

Comment: @ChethanShetty You add Runnable to messages queue, just remove callbacks `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)`, put it in onStop() method of Activity or maybe even after startService(). Even without it thread is on IDLE after `run()` method ends.

Comment: If u want to stop AlarmManager work repeatedly every 10 seconds use `alarmManager.cancel(PENDING_INTENT)`

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
alarmManagera.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),10000, YourPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code Snippet may help you

```
 private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 30*1000;  
  AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
            service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
```

In MyService class use `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`. you have used  onStart(Intent intent, int startId) which will execute once.

```
public class MyService extends Service 
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }//End of onBind method

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
    {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onStartCommand=Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kalai.G but issue remains.

Comment: Thanks @Kalai.G but issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

replace `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` with `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Thanks @Shakeeb Shaheen but its not helping.