# Start Service in a new Thread and run from it AsyncTask with Activity refernace

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a `AsyncTask` that written in separate file. I call it with `Activity context` and in `onPostExecute` I notify the `Activity` about data by implementing `Interface`.

```
public myResponse myDelegate = null;
protected void onPostExecute(List<IsDataPersonal> data) {
    myDelegate.setData(data);
}
```

My `Activity` also implements this `Interface` and registered to this method.

How can I call to a `Service` in a new `Thread`, and run it from `AsyncTask`call and notify the Main Activity with the results data, Do I need to run the service from `Main Activity` and pass activity context and then pass it to `AsyncTask`

Comment: So you want to run the AsyncTask from a service?  Any reason why you don't want to just execute the task from the Activity?  I think calling back to the Activity from onPostExecute is fine.  That's how I do it in one of my apps.

Comment: I want the service will run it every 20 minutes...

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020853/how-to-run-some-task-at-specified-time-interval-in-android-using-alarmmanager